# can't make element return to it's original state using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the box translate on the X axis by `500px` then return to it's original status, why the same logic work on the title element but not on the box.
(note : I'm new at using `JavaScript`)

```js
function colorChange() {
    let title = document.getElementById('title');
    if (title.style.color != 'red') {
        title.innerText = 'I\'m Red';
        title.style.color = 'red';
        title.style.transition = '2s';
        title.style.animationDelay = '3s';
        title.style.transform = 'rotateZ(360deg)';
    }
    else {
        title.innerText = 'I\'m Black';
        title.style.color = 'black';
        title.style.transition = '2s';
        title.style.animationDelay = '3s';
        title.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-360deg)';
    }
}
function boxTranslate() {
    let boxElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    if (boxElement.style.color != 'red') {
        boxElement.style.background = 'red';
        boxElement.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
        boxElement.style.transition = '1s';
    }
    else {
        boxElement.style.background = 'royalblue';
        boxElement.style.transform = 'translateX(-500px)';
        boxElement.style.transition = '1s';
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
}
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="title" onclick="colorChange()">I'm Black</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="big-box">
        <div onclick="boxTranslate()" class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are comparing with the "color" style but setting the "background". Change your condition from color to background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code.

1. At the box you check `boxElement.style.color != 'red'`  but you need to check the `background` not the `color`
2. To return it to the initial position, use `transform:translateX(0)` because that's the initial position of the box before you translate it 500px on the x-axis.

The same you should do to the text. `rotateZ(0deg)`

When you use `transform` on an element. You do not change it's initial/default position, but you just 'edit/manipulate' it's position on the screen. It's initial position by default is still `0`. That's why if you translate the box 500px you do not need to use `-500px`but instead use `0`, because  `transform:translate(-500px)` would move the box from it's current position 500px to the left of it's default/initial position.

```js
function colorChange() {
    let title = document.getElementById('title');
    if (title.style.color != 'red') {
        title.innerText = 'I\'m Red';
        title.style.color = 'red';
        title.style.transition = '2s';
        title.style.animationDelay = '3s';
        title.style.transform = 'rotateZ(360deg)';
    }
    else {
        title.innerText = 'I\'m Black';
        title.style.color = 'black';
        title.style.transition = '2s';
        title.style.animationDelay = '3s';
        title.style.transform = 'rotateZ(0deg)';
    }
}
function boxTranslate() {
    let boxElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    if (boxElement.style.background != 'red') {
        boxElement.style.background = 'red';
        boxElement.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
        boxElement.style.transition = '1s';
    }
    else {
        boxElement.style.background = 'royalblue';
        boxElement.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)';
        boxElement.style.transition = '1s';
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
}
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="title" onclick="colorChange()">I'm Black</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="big-box">
        <div onclick="boxTranslate()" class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how I couldn't saw that I'm calling the wrong property, that kind of embarrassing, and also thanks for the advice for returning to the original status . that's work .

Answer (score 1):

because your if statement depends on `style.color`, but you set `style.background`. You need to change your if-statement to:

```
if (boxElement.style.background != 'red') {
```

Comment: while this solves the problem of the `if` condition, it doesn't return the box to it's initial value

Answer (score 1):

It works on your text because you were checking for the `.color` style and not the `.background` style see my example below for a fixed version. In addition to changing the if statement you also need to update the else `transform:translateX` option to be 0

```js
function colorChange() {
    let title = document.getElementById('title');
    if (title.style.color != 'red') {
        title.innerText = 'I\'m Red';
        title.style.color = 'red';
        title.style.transition = '2s';
        title.style.animationDelay = '3s';
        title.style.transform = 'rotateZ(360deg)';
    }
    else {
        title.innerText = 'I\'m Black';
        title.style.color = 'black';
        title.style.transition = '2s';
        title.style.animationDelay = '3s';
        title.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-360deg)';
    }
}
function boxTranslate() {
    let boxElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    if (boxElement.style.background != 'red' ) {
        boxElement.style.background = 'red';
        boxElement.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
        boxElement.style.transition = '1s';
    }
    else {
        boxElement.style.background = 'royalblue';
        boxElement.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
        boxElement.style.transition = '1s';
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
}
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="title" onclick="colorChange()">I'm Black</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="big-box">
        <div onclick="boxTranslate()" class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```